# Not able to replace null values in Spark Dataframe with Integer value

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

[image: Employee Dataframe]

In my Employees DataFrame I want to replace null values in commission column with a specific value (let it be 500). I am using below command to replace all null values but I dont know what should be the key value for null in Map:

```
    `employeeDF.na.replace("commission", Map("" -> 1000)).show()`

I am getting this error :

    <console>:32: error: type mismatch;
         found   : scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int]
         required: Map[Any,Any]
        Note: String <: Any, but trait Map is invariant in type A.
        You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Any`. (SLS 3.2.10)
               employeeDF.na.replace("commission", Map("" -> 1000)).show()

What should I put in key part  of map ??
```

Comment: This would be much easier if you use spark sql or dataframe api methods of spark

Comment: try this - create new data frame, val newDf = employeeDF.na.fill("500",Seq("comission"))

Comment: not worked still null values

Comment: @sach try this it will help you df.na.fill(Map("commission" -> 500)).show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either of the two:

```
employeeDF.na.fill(1000, Seq("commission")).show()


import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
employeeDF.withColumn("commission", when(col("commission").isNull, 1000) otherwise col("commission")).show()
```